# Is it possible to draw using opengl on a directx dc/buffer?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, directx, directx-11

This is probably a stupid question, but I cant find good examples on how to approach this, or if its even possible. Im just done with a project where I used gdi to biblt stuff onto a DIB-buffer then swap that onto the screen hdc, basically making my own swapchain and drawing with opengl.

So then I thought, can I do the same thing using directx11? But I cant seem to find where the DIB/buffer I need to change even is.

Am I even thinking about this correctly? Any ideas on how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Nvidia exposes vendor-specific extensions called [NV_DX_interop](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/DX_interop.txt) and [NV_DX_Interop2](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/DX_interop2.txt). With these extensions, you can directly access a DirectX surface (when it resides on the GPU) and render to it from an OpenGL context. There should be minimal (driver-only) overhead for this operation and the CPU will almost never be involved.

Note that while this is a vendor-specific extension, [Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/texture-sharing-from-intel-media-sdk-to-opengl) GPUs support it as well.

*However, don't do this simply for the fun of it or if you control all the source code for your application. This kind of interop scenario is meant for cases where you have two legacy/complicated codebases and interop is a cheaper/better option than porting all the logic to the other API.*

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do it, both OpenGL and D3D support both writeable textures and locking them to get to the pixel data.

Simply render your scene in OpenGL to a texture, lock it, read the pixel data and pass it directly to the D3D locked texture pixel data, unlock it then do whatever you want with the texture.

Performance would be dreadful of course, you're stalling the GPU multiple times in a single "operation" and forcing it to synchronize with the CPU (who's passing the data) and the bus (for memory access). Plus there would be absolutely no benefit at all. But if you really want to try it, you can do it.

Comment: so its a bad idea then? I was hoping to draw directly to the directx swapchain buffer, kinda using dx only to blt stuff onto screen

Comment: so should i focus on opengl when trying to do graphics, or is directx more powerful? u have any idea? im leaning towards opengl, but im worried ill lose control over the window itself

Comment: They're equally powerful

Comment: what if i want to keep control of the window itself? seems like opengl calls (glew) make use of a standard window

Comment: No, this is not true. There is a way to render using OpenGL onto a DirectX surface resident on GPU memory with no transfers involved.

Comment: Thats what I suspected, where to find information about it tho?

Comment: In hindsight, googling "OpenGL DirectX interop" brings up some results, but I knew about this extension having investigated this for a previous project of mine.